# What is the upper limit of ADF array variable?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I find there is an activity call **Append Variable**, so how many items I can insert into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation on this for Data Factory. However, ADF shares some DNA with Logic Apps, which states a maximum number of array items as 100,000. [Logic Apps Limits - Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal#variables-action-limits)

Answer (score 1):

in the document of [ForEach Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity),  the maximum number ForEach can process is 100,000. so, the maximum capacity of an array ForEach can receive is 100,000.

> The ForEach activity has a maximum batchCount of 50 for parallel processing, and a maximum of 100,000 items.

Answer (score 0):

We can create arrays of any length using [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#range).

Create a pipeline. Add a variable of type array. Add a set variable activity. Set the variable's value to the expression `@range(1, 100001)`. Run the pipeline.

It throws an exception

> The function 'range' parameters are out of range: 'count' must be a positive integer no larger than '100000' and the sum of 'start index' and 'count' must be no larger than 2147483647.

Sure enough, reducing the expression's upper limit to 100000 does not throw an error. So the maximum length of an array is 100,000 items.